# Non-numeric range search

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm indexing logs, including the levels and I am tired of doing stringed-together query's of `"INFO OR DEBUG OR TRACE"`, is there any way, either specific to ElasticSearch or to Lucene to allow you to specify a range that is non numeric, so I could do something like `"level:>=INFO"`?

Comment: `INFO OR DEBUG OR TRACE` is the only way it makes sense to do this.  How would either technology be able to draw the conclusion that both `DEBUG` and `TRACE` are greater than `INFO`?  If you are tired of rewriting the same query logic, create an object or factory that takes care of it for you.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a sort of Enum available to Lucene with ordered elements. I assumed not, be thought it would be best to ask before giving up.

Comment: Okay, I see what your after.  I'm not aware of anything quite like that, out of the box, but extending [MultiTermQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiTermQuery.html), and override getTermsEnum to provide the appropriate [FilteredTermsEnum](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/FilteredTermsEnum.html) for this case.

Comment: Using elasticsearch, you can probably achieve something like that using a [script filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/script-filter/), but that's hackish and potentially slow.

Answer (score 0):

In Lucene you could do this:

```
level:[DEBUG TO TRACE]
```

but this will enable any level that is alphabetically between those two (including them, use {} to exclude).

Update: it might be some time till this is added to Solr (if it is added) but [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5084) would be what you need

Comment: You can do the same with elasticsearch, as well as use a [range query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/range-query/) which works for strings too. But still, it would rely on the alphabetic order, which is not what @Nicholas was hoping for.